# Count a value in a column in a data frame in R programming

Tags: r

Hi my data looks like below:

```
Product Price Quantity Returns 
Fridge  $260  20       3 
Oven    $150  12       #N/A 
Iron    $100  #N/A     5 
Stove   $150  20       #N/A
```

I want R to return the number of times "#N/A" appears in the column Returns.

Thanks for the help. I'm new to R and trying to self teach.

Comment: will this work? df$[ ,4][df[ ,4] == "#N/A"]<- NA

Answer (score 4):

```
df$Returns[df$Returns == "#N/A"] <- NA
sum(is.na(df$Returns))
```

should do the trick. It first checks which values of `df$Returns` are `NA`. Next we use the fact that in `sum` `TRUE` is interpreted as `1` and `FALSE` as `0` to get the total number of NA's.

Comment: Why not directly: `sum(df$Returns == "#N/A")`?

Comment: Also possible, but transforming the `#N/A` is good practice as e.g. plotting routines know how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `table` to your `Returns` column :

```
table(df$Returns)
```

You can then display a specific value this way :

```
tab <- table(df$Returns)
tab["#N/A"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Returns<- subset(df, df$Returns=="#N/A")
nrow(Returns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your dataframe in variable  `x`, whose 4th column is `Returns` and you want to count the number of `#NA`.

Run the command on R console as:

```
table(is.na(x[,4]))
```

and take the value of `TRUE`